# LineUnavailableException when loading audio clip with Java on RPi

Tags: audio, raspbian-jessie, java

My RPi is Zero W and using Raspbian Jessie 4.9.35 / Oracle JDK8 1.8.0_65.

I'm having problem with loading audio clips on Java Program with RPi.
I have two audio files named "piano_0.wav" and "piano_1.wav" and they are different audio files.

I used this to load the clip:

```
Clip loadClip(String path) {
    Clip clip = null;
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));
        clip.open(stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(MusicManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return clip;
}
```

When I try to load piano_0.wav, there's no error logs and can play returned Clip. but When I try to load piano_1.wav program throws exception:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1304)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1085)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1175)
at beatstairscmd.BeatStairsCMD.testMusicClip(BeatStairsCMD.java:81)
at beatstairscmd.BeatStairsCMD.main(BeatStairsCMD.java:42)
```

But when I used this code on my Desktop there's no problem to load more clips.
I already tried solutions with init the clip with other ways instead of **AudioSystem.getClip()** and there's no changes.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by passing a different Mixer to getClip(MixerInfo) rather than relying on the default action of getClip(). I first called AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() to get a list of the audio mixers available and print them out to the console. Then I just tried them one my one until I found one that worked (actually, it was the second one, so it didn't take too long).